# XPages Loading Slow with IBM HTTP Server Enabled

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We are having an issue with slow loading XPages when the IBM HTTP server is enabled. With the IBM HTTP server disabled, XPage applications load fast.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening or settings to look for?

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile running XPages Toolbox, to check whether there is any difference in performance of XPages itself with it enabled and disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I should have also mentioned that this same XPages application loads fast on a different server with IBM HTTP Server enabled which makes me think that it isn't an application issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. There was a value incorrect in the HTTP response header rule in the server config.